# Accessing DOM element in an iframe and outside an iframe with one code line using Jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have a page which contains a div.

CODE

```
<div id="main_data">My main div</div>
```

I am also hosting this page within an iframe at another page (Parent Page).

I have a function that hides/shows the div that runs when one clicks on a button.
I am calling the function from the page itself and from the parent page which host the page.

Right now i am using this code to access the "Main_data" div from the page itself

```
var element = $('#main_data');
```

And i am using this code to access the "Main_data" div from the parent page which host the page within an iframe.

The "graphFrame" is the ID of the iframe in the parent page

```
var element = $('#graphFrame').contents().find("#main_data");
```

That means i am duplicating code, and i don't like it.
I am wondering if there is a way to access the DOM element with one line of code which will fit for both cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see much code is duplicated and I don't think it's very necessary to use this:

```
function accessor(selector){
    return ($('iframe').length ? $('iframe').contents() : $(documents)).find(selector);
}
```

not tested